# Animate right, or up not working

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, jquery-animate

I am trying to have a box with two options and I want it to animate and fadeout to the left when I click option 1 and animate and fadeout to the right when I select option two. Unfortunately, it only animates left and up, not right which I want. (nor does it animate bottom). What can i do to solve this.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$(".appIMG2").one('click.appIMG2', function() {
    $('.appIMG1, .appIMG2').unbind('click');
    $('#app1').animate({
        right: "250px",
        opacity:0
    });
    $("#app3").fadeIn("slow");
    });
});

#app1{
position:absolute;
width:250px;
height:250px;
z-index:10;
top:50%;
left:50%;
margin:-150px 0 0 -150px;
background:white;
box-shadow: 0 0 1px 1px #888888;
text-align:center;
}
```

I'm assuming it's something to with how I declare the margins of #app1,2 and 3 but I cant figure it out.

http://jsfiddle.net/7tgJC/

Comment: Consider adding `jsfiddle`.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly to say you're better off showing your HTML as well - in a Fiddle preferably.

I do believe you're seeing is the intended and default behaviour of Fade-in/Animate. If you want it to FadeIn/Animate in different directions, you *could* to utilise [jQuery Slide](http://api.jqueryui.com/slide-effect/) with the direction parameter with the [jQuery UI](http://api.jqueryui.com/) library.

```
<script>
$('#examplediv').hide("slide", { direction: "right" }, function() {
   //Some Code.
});
</script>
```

But indeed you're better off removing those margins, see this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SMrcy/4/) without the margins: http://jsfiddle.net/SMrcy/4/ with it animating right.